# What's the counterpart to glGetMatrix() (and why isn't glSetMatrix() it?!!!)?

Tags: opengl

Ok, I've been convinced that quaternions are The Way To Go, rather than trying to make pitch, yaw, roll rotations work out.  So now I've got code that looks something like this (obj-C, but it shouldn't matter):

```
[quaternion makeIdentity];
[quaternion setPitch: rotation.x yaw: rotation.y roll: rotation.z];

GLfloat matrix[16];
[quaternion stuffMatrix: &matrix];
matrix[12] = location.x;
matrix[13] = location.y;
matrix[14] = location.z;
// Now what?
// glSetMatrix(matrix); //  No, that's not right, is it?!
```

Once I've set my quaternion to deal with the various rotations and stuffed the values into my matrix array, how do I set the current matrix to those values?

Thanks!

P.S. Yes, I'm an Open-GL n00b.  Sorry if this is basic stuff; I just can't seem to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

glPushMatrix or glLoadMatrix is what you're looking for

Comment: glLoadMatrix.  Thank you.  (I knew about push & pop...)